# Passing a node to be transposed to front of list

Tags: c++

I have implemented my own list that holds templated nodes. I'm passing my own objects into the nodes. I tried creating a function that moves a node to the front of the list.

This is my move to front function (which is declared in my list called DLL which resides in DLL.h):

```
void make_head(const T& *ptr) {
            if(ptr != head){
                if(ptr != tail){
                    ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
                    ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
                }
                else{
                    ptr->prev->next = NULL;
                    tail = ptr->prev;
                }
                head->prev = ptr;
                ptr->next = head;
                ptr->prev = NULL;

                head = ptr;
            }
        }
```

Heres where I call the function:

```
for(DLL<Play>::iterator itr=ChangingList.begin(); itr!=ChangingList.end(); itr++){
                if( (*itr).getRC() >= 3 ){
                    ChangingList.make_head((itr));
                }
            }
```

I get - error: no matching function for call to âDLL::make_head(Iterator&)â
DLL.h:107: note: candidates are: void DLL::make_head(const T*) [with T = Play]

How can I reference the node's pointer to pass through the parameters in order to correctly use my function?

Comment: where is `make_head` function is declared? what file, what class?

Comment: Sorry, it's been added.

Comment: what type of ChangingList? how it is declared?

Comment: DLL<Play> ChangingList;

Comment: ok, try to change `ChangingList.make_head((itr));` to `ChangingList.make_head(*itr);`

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error.

Comment: are you sure, can you copy-paste new error?

Comment: `main.cpp:295: error: no matching function for call to âDLL<Play>::make_head(Play&)â
DLL.h:107: note: candidates are: void DLL<T>::make_head(const T*) [with T = Play]
make: *** [main.o] Error 1`

Comment: ok, use `ChangingList.make_head( &(*itr) );`

Comment: `DLL.h:110: error: âconst class Playâ has no member named âprevâ`

Comment: oh, now we comes to another parts of code, did you defined prev member of Play class?

Comment: No, I defined it as a member of DLL. I want it to transpose the templated node though, shouldn't the fact that it's templated take care of that?

Comment: so, I suppose the error is clear and you can solve it?

Comment: Supposing you are calling with `ChangingList.make_head( &(*itr) )`, I think you should declare `void make_head(T *ptr)`.

Comment: actually you should have list templated, listnode templated and iterator templated, then you will have you're nodes as Play, but listnodes will use internal listnode to store actual node/prev/next and pointer to Play (which is T)

Comment: @iavr this will work too, but problem here is much deeper, as OP do not understand basic data structures and how they can be implemented

Comment: @Will, maybe start with standard implementations - check how they work, then try to copy and add your method

Comment: My list, listnode, and iterator are all templated.